# Assign object to parent type with parent parameterized type

Tags: c#, generics

Below is sample code:

```
public interface C1 { }
public class C2 : C1 { }

public interface MK<T> { }

public struct MKSub : MK<C2> { }

public class Test
{
    void Something()
    {
        MK<C1> test = new MKSub(); // Somehow make it so this will work?
    }
}
```

Is there some way to modify this so that the assignment on the commented line will work?

If it weren't for the parameterized types `MK test = new MKSub();` would of course work. But is there something that can be done to the generic type declarations or something so that the above assignment will also work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use covariance operator `out` on your interface `MK`:

```
public interface C1 { }
public class C2 : C1 { }

public interface MK<out T> { }   // use <out T> instead of <T>

public struct MKSub : MK<C2> { }

public class Test
{
    void Something()
    {
        MK<C1> test = new MKSub();    // this compiles
    }
}
```

Covariance and contravariance is generics is too big topic to explain in this answer, but you can read more about it [on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Worked perfect. I just couldn't find what that operator was. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it only if your interface `MK` uses `T` only as output of any methods, and never as input. Then you can do this:

```
public interface MK<out T> {
    T MakeT<Q>(Q other) where Q : T;
}
```

However, if you try doing this

```
public interface MK<out T> {
    void ConsumeT(T val);
}
```

you will get a compile-time error:

> The covariant type parameter `T` must be contravariantly valid on `Test.MK<T>.ConsumeT(T)`